# How can i add className in ReactDOM.createRoot() dynamically along with Id?

Tags: reactjs, element, react-dom

I want to add `className` in `reactDOM` root element.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should have to pass class to your `<App className={'xyz'}/>`

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App  className={'xyz'} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```